# Having trouble retrieving value from tableview

Tags: javafx, tableview

I'm having having trouble getting a correct output from tableview. I'm using a button to set one item from tableview to a label. However, it prints "StringProperty [Value pineapples]" where I would like it to be just "pineapples".

The tableview gives them correctly.

```
public class ProductListController implements Initializable {

@FXML public TableView<Model> tableview ;
@FXML private TableColumn<Model, Number> ProductID;
@FXML private TableColumn<Model, String> ProductName;
@FXML private TableColumn<Model, Number> ProductPrice; 
@FXML private Label lblProduct;
@FXML private Label lblPrice;   

@FXML
private void btnActionShow(ActionEvent event) {

  assert tableview !=null : " ";
         ProductID.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().ProductIDProperty());
         ProductName.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().ProductNameProperty());
         ProductPrice.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().ProductPriceProperty());

            buildData();        
    }

private ObservableList<Model> data;

public void buildData(){
    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    try{
   Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
      ("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Stock", "*****", "*****");

     Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
     String SQL = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS";
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

    while (rs.next()) {
      Model mod = new Model();
     mod.ProductID.set(rs.getInt("ID"));
     mod.ProductName.set(rs.getString("NAME"));
     mod.ProductPrice.set(rs.getInt("SELL_PRICE"));


     data.add(mod);
     }
     tableview.setItems(data);

     }
    catch ( SQLException err) {
    System.out.println(err.getMessage() );
    }
   }


//Button to fetch data from Tableview. Sets the data not the way I want.
@FXML
private void btnConfirmAction(ActionEvent event) {
    Model model = tableview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    String prd;
    prd = model.getProductName().toString();
    lblProduct.setText(prd);
}


   @FXML
private void btnNextAction(ActionEvent event) {

   try{
     FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/appl/Discount.fxml"));
       Parent parent = loader.load();
         DiscountController discountcontr = loader.getController();
         discountcontr.setProduct(tableview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getProductName().toString());

         Stage stage = new Stage();
         Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
         stage.setScene(scene);
         stage.show();

     }
     catch(IOException e){
     }
}


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }    

}
```

Model

```
public class Model {

    public SimpleIntegerProperty ProductID = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    public SimpleStringProperty ProductName = new SimpleStringProperty ();
    public SimpleIntegerProperty ProductPrice = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    private final SimpleBooleanProperty Checked = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    public SimpleBooleanProperty checkedProperty() {
        return this.Checked;
    }

    public java.lang.Boolean getChecked() {
        return this.checkedProperty().get();
    }

    public void setChecked(final java.lang.Boolean checked) {
        this.checkedProperty().set(checked);
    }


    public SimpleIntegerProperty getProductID() {
        return ProductID;
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getProductName() {
        return ProductName;
    }

    public SimpleIntegerProperty getProductPrice() {
        return ProductPrice;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `getProductName()` returns a `SimpleStringProperty`, you need to retrieve the String from it using the `get()`. Just use :

```
String prd = model.getProductName().get();
```

Comment: Yeah ofcourse, Seems obvious now. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Ophichius But, as James_D mentioned, you must always use the Model correctly and your getter should do the job of getting the String out of the StringProperty.

Comment: Ah, I see whay you mean. That will save code and is neater. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

Your model is implemented incorrectly. You should use the following pattern:

```
public class Model {

    private SimpleStringProperty productName = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public SimpleStringProperty productNameProperty() {
        return productName ;
    }

    public final String getProductName() {
        return productNameProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setProductName(String productName) {
        productNameProperty().set(productName);
    }

}
```

and similarly for the other properties.

If you use the e(fx)clipse plugin, you can generate the methods automatically from the property definition by right-clicking, choosing "Source" and then "Generate JavaFX Getters and Setters". I think NetBeans has similar functionality.

Comment: Yes Netbeans can generate Getters and Setters. Can you explain me why this is better? Or the disadvantage of my model?

Comment: It follows the JavaBeans pattern: e.g. you have a `productName` property of type `String`, as enforced by the `String getPropertyName()` and `void setPropertyName(String pName)` methods. Also, the `TableView` is designed to work with the `productNameProperty()` method, which it expects to return an `ObservableValue<String>` for a `String` property (`StringProperty` implements this). This means you can use a [`PropertyValueFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html), and you get automatic updating if the table is editable.

Comment: Have a look at the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm#JFXBD107). The [API docs for `PropertyValueFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html) also give some insight into how this is used.

Comment: Thank you. That tutorial was clarifying.